# Why is the regression curve not (displayed) linear(ly)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have this data

```
  Resistance CO_part_l H2_part_l C2H2_part_l rH T_amb
1   7.334982  44.59499  2.33e+19    6.95e+17 36    25
2   7.192182  44.59499  2.33e+19    6.95e+17 36    25
3   7.548556  44.59499  2.33e+19    6.95e+17 36    25
4   7.287561  44.59499  2.33e+19    6.95e+17 36    25
5   5.476464  44.59499  2.33e+19    6.95e+17 36    25
6   5.433722  44.59499  2.33e+19    6.95e+17 36    25
```

and I wanna' use this model:

```
m4<- lm(Resistance ~ (CO_part_l + H2_part_l + C2H2_part_l + rH + T_amb), data = df)
```

then to predict the values via

```
pred_df <- data.frame(R_pred = predict(m4, df), CO_part_l = df$CO_part_l)
```

and plot it finally:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(Resistance))) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(color='red',data = pred_df, aes(x=exp(CO_part_l), y=exp(R_pred)), alpha = 0.5, size =1.15) +
  theme_bw() + xlab(TeX("CO / [part/l]")) + ylab(TeX("R / $ \\Omega $ ")) + labs(title="CO")
```

and I don't understand why it looks like pieces of linear functions connected to each other..

[image: plot]

Note: `Resistance` and `CO_part_l` is logarithmized in the dataset because the relationship is logarithmic and to center it I have to do that in advance. That's why I exponentiate it in the plot then.

You can find the entire data here https://workupload.com/file/WuwqNeyKnAk
I used the `dput` output, so I hope you can read it in.

Comment: What do you expect it to look like? Remember you are plotting only two variables of the regression against each other but you are showing a prediction that takes into account H2_part_l, C2H2_part_l, rH and T_amb, which will all have different values at each value of CO. In other words, the line would only be straight if CO was completely independent from the other independent variables.

Comment: you have to fix your other variables and predict, to see the effect of CO..

Comment: I assumed that somehow..  so this means I have almost no possibility to visualize that regression?

Comment: Ben you can view this aspect of the regression - like @StupidWolf says. You can get a prediction on varying CO while holding the covariates at their means.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood to "fix" as something like "repair/get it done".. I'm not a native speaker :) Is there an easy way to do so? Or do you mean I shall create appropriate data frames for each effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a single smooth line through the plot, you can hold the covariates steady (at their means, for example) while changing only the variable plotted on your x axis. In your case, the code to produce the prediction set might look something like this:

```r
pred_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(40, 45.2, 0.1), function(x)
  within(as.data.frame(t(colMeans(df)[3:6])), CO_part_l <- x)
))
```

Now `pred_df` is a data frame of all your regressors held at their means apart from `CO_part_l` which is varied evenly throughout its range. We can use this to see how the output variable changes according to a change in `CO_part_l` when all else is equal:

```r
pred_df$R_pred <- predict(m4, newdata = pred_df)
```

And that means your plot will look like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(Resistance))) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(color = 'red',data = pred_df, 
            aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(R_pred)), 
            alpha = 0.5, size = 1.15) +
  theme_bw() + xlab(TeX("CO / [part/l]")) + 
  ylab(TeX("R / $ \\Omega $ ")) + 
  labs(title="CO")
```

[image]

This probably looks more convincing on a log scale (or just not exponentiating your y axis; I'm not sure of the physical relevance of the numbers, so I'll simply add a log scale here)

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(Resistance))) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(color = 'red',data = pred_df, 
            aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(R_pred)), 
            alpha = 0.5, size = 1.15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab(TeX("CO / [part/l]")) + 
  ylab(TeX("R / $ \\Omega $ ")) + 
  labs(title="CO") +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

And of course, making the x axis a `scale_x_log10` would give a straight line, though not quite as nice a plot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(Resistance))) + 
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(color = 'red',data = pred_df, 
            aes(x = exp(CO_part_l), y = exp(R_pred)), 
            alpha = 0.5, size = 1.15) +
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab(TeX("CO / [part/l]")) + 
  ylab(TeX("R / $ \\Omega $ ")) + 
  labs(title="CO") +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]